# I need pick up highest counts

Tags: sql

This is the query I am using in SQL

```
select distinct  d.npa, n.time_zone, count(n.time_zone) as tz_count 

from  #duplicates d

inner join psi.npanxx n
on d.npa = n.npa

where n.time_zone is not null and n.time_zone <> '0'

group by --d.npanxx_row_id, d.npa, n.time_zone

order by npa
```

I get the result something like this

```
npa        time_zone                tz_count
208           5                      10600
208           4                      31300
219           6                       7882
219           9                       7446
```

and I need to get only with the highest counts so it looks like this

```
npa        time_zone                tz_count
208           5                      10600
219           6                       7882
```

If there is any function I can use please let me know.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: can I ask what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `COUNT`, the correct SQL keyword is `MAX`

```
select distinct  d.npa, n.time_zone, max(n.time_zone) as tz_count 

from  #duplicates d

inner join psi.npanxx n
on d.npa = n.npa

where n.time_zone is not null and n.time_zone <> '0'

group by --d.npanxx_row_id, d.npa, n.time_zone

order by npa
```

Here is an example fiddle. It uses a different data set, but uses the same `MAX-Group BY` formula.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d871e/1/0

Comment: It Worked Thank You Richard

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to +1 this post if you found it interesting

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select d.npa, d.time_zone, d.tz_count
from (select d.npa, n.time_zone, count(*) as tz_count,
             row_number() over (partition by npa order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from #duplicates d inner join
           psi.npanxx n
           on d.npa = n.npa
      where n.time_zone is not null and n.time_zone <> '0'
      group by d.npa, n.time_zone
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```